# Gradle user home

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is there a way to access the gradle user home directory which could be set by GRADLE_USER_HOME or -g somedir or the default value from within my build.gradle file?

If I run a gradle build with --debug it prints out the user home but I can't find a way to access it by any variable.

example printout:
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: /some/dir

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In you gradle build script you can access it via:

```
project.gradle.gradleUserHomeDir
```

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html) for more details

Comment: and if i need to get home/user?